# SMSGlobal Soap Example

Tags: c#, soap

I'm trying to consume SMSGlobal service in my code, the API in their web site is not clear that much and I could not find any example.

I'm trying to send SMS, here is my code:

```
SMSGlobal.MobileWorks mobileWorks = new SMSGlobal.MobileWorks();
string ticket = mobileWorks.apiValidateLogin(<username>, <password>);

string res = mobileWorks.apiSendSms(ticket ....);// couldn't know the parameters values
```

**EDIT:**
Here the the paramters should be passed (taken from API in SMSGloabal web site)

```
<part name="ticket" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="sms_from" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="sms_to" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="msg_content" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="msg_type" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="unicode" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="schedule" type="xsd:string"/>
```

"tikcet" will be taken from the first line of code, but I don't know what to pass for rest parameters

Comment: Please make sure to provide more info regarding what's not working.

Comment: mobileWorks.apiSendSms returns error 402 since I don't know what data should be passed. I have updated the question

Comment: You should ask this question to the particular company's support staff. There website seems super dated, I couldn't get to their documentation on a quick look. Wondering why you chose this provider over other companies?

Comment: Here is their documentation:
https://www.smsglobal.com/soap-api/
this provider has choose by customer.
Unfortunately I didn't find any example by searching everywhere